# deleting managed metadata using powershell script sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell

Deleting managed metadata term stores using powershell script. Was trying with the below script but getting error "Cannot index into null array". Please help out thanks in advance....

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
Clear-Host
$taxonomySite = get-SPSite "http://"
$mmsServiceName = "Managed Metadata Service"
#$taxonomySite = Get-SPSite $centralAdminURL
$taxSession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $taxonomySite
$termStore = $taxSession.TermStores[$config.configuration.configSettings.mmsServiceName]
$grpName = "XXX"
$grpManager = ""
$termSetName = ""
$termSetOwner = ""
$tsStakeHolder = ""
Clear-Host 
$group = $termStore.Groups["XXX"]
if ($contentsource -ne $null)
{
    $contentsource.Delete()
}

if ($termStore -ne $null)
{

    if ($group -ne $null)
    {
        $group.TermSets|foreach{
            $_.Delete()
            $termStore.CommitAll()
        }
        $group.Delete()
        $termStore.CommitAll()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending sometime found the solution just need to mention the terms

```
#Script for deleting managed metadata 
#Calling Taxonomy site and group Name
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
Clear-Host 
$taxonomySite = get-SPSite "http:" 
$mmsServiceName = "Managed Metadata Service"
$grpName = "XXX"
$grpManager = "YYY"
$termSetName = "XXXX"
$termSetOwner = ""
$tsStakeHolder = ""
$centralAdmin = "XXXXXX"
#$termsetName = "VVV"
#$grpName = "XXXX"

        $site = Get-SPSite $centralAdmin
        $session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
        $termStore = $Session.TermStores[$mmsServiceName];
        $group=$termStore.Groups[$grpName]
        $group.TermSets|foreach{
            $_.Delete()
            $termstore.CommitAll()
        }
        $group.Delete()
        $termstore.CommitAll()

        Write-Output "Deleted $groupName"
```

Comment: You can remove the CommitAll in the inner foreach

Answer (score -1):

`$site = Get-SPSite $centralAdmin` is not necessary, just use `$taxonomySite` in TaxonmySession ... also last line should be Write-Output "`Deleted $grpName`" not `$groupName` ....